# Why unexpected bubble shows in my R leaflet map (leaflet.minicharts)?

Tags: r, dictionary, leaflet, bubble-chart

I plan to make a map which can show the transition of entities and their capacity by years by using R leaflet.

In this small example, 2017 only have few entities and lower NameplateCapacityMW. In 2019, entities' number is increased and NameplateCapacityMW's capacity is also changed.

I faced some problems. I hope more capacity show more close to dark green, lower capacity more close to light green. But, in my code, it shows blue(leaflet default color) bubbles in 2019.  How to fix it?

Besides, 2019 bubbles should not show in 2017 map, but they showed, how to avoid this situation?

```html
# Small Example 
library(readr)
MonthYear <- c("5/1/2019","5/1/2019","5/1/2019","5/1/2019","5/1/2019","4/1/2017","4/1/2017","4/1/2017")
EntityName <- c("FPL","GM","GM","TL","MT","FPL","GM","SL")
NameplateCapacityMW <- c(16,2,1,3.1,2,15,1,1)
Latitude <- c(43.7508,43.619444,44.085795,41.381256,42.451836,43.7508,43.619444,42.451836)
Longitude <- c(-70.1567,-72.95028,-73.19539,-72.07689,-72.603,-70.1567,-72.95028,-71.73775)

AllData <- data.frame(MonthYear,EntityName,NameplateCapacityMW,Latitude,Longitude)

View(AllData)
head(AllData)

library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(readr)
library(leaflet.minicharts)
library(htmltools)


rc1 <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("#ddedf0", "#42aa86"), space = "Lab")(100)
rc2 <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("#42aa86", "#004318"), space = "Lab")(100)
rampcols <- c(rc1, rc2)
mypal2 <- colorNumeric(palette = rampcols, domain = AllData$NameplateCapacityMW)


leaflet(AllData) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  fitBounds(~min(AllData$Longitude), ~min(AllData$Latitude), ~max(AllData$Longitude), ~max(AllData$Latitude))%>%
  addMinicharts(
    AllData$Longitude, AllData$Latitude,
    chartdata = AllData$NameplateCapacityMW,
    time = AllData$MonthYear,
    fillColor = mypal2(AllData$NameplateCapacityMW),
    width = 45, height = 45)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA2rY.gif)

Comment: Do you have NA values for the field `Nameplate.Capacity..MW.` in the last year?

Comment: Thank you. I checked it, the data do not have NA. So sad.

Comment: How long is latitude and nameplate.capacity? Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will make one.

Comment: Hello David and Christoph, I posted a small example just now. Looking forward to hearing your advice!